# Use a div class number to make an account

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables

I am trying to create an account, and as an example I am trying to add the amount of a tax to a value that would be **$ 10**, and the tax would be **$ 5**.

But I can't make this sum :(

Could someone help me please?

```js
function displayTax() {
      
      var tax = this.gsx$taxvalue.$t ;
    
      $('.taxClass').html(tax);
      
      var item = 10;
      var total = item + tax;
      

      $('.total-count').html(item);
      
      $('.total-tax').html(total.toFixed(2));
      
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   
 var sheetURL =
"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1j3ri1WPLuw6IXXKYqrqNkSe_vU__YEXjyUSusR6G7ss/1/public/values?alt=json";
 $.getJSON(sheetURL, function(data) {
   var entryData = data.feed.entry;
   console.log(data);
   jQuery.each(entryData, function() {
     
     
     $("#valueTax").append(
       ' <div>' + this.gsx$taxvalue.$t + '</div>'
      );
   });
  });
});
   
 displayTax();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    
<div class="total-count"></div>
    
<div>Value Tax:<span class="taxClass"></span> </div>
<div id="valueTax"></div>

<br>

<div>Total with tax: $<span class="total-tax"></span></div>
```

Comment: It looks like the summing takes place in the displayTax function, but I don't see anything that calls that function.  What is supposed to call it?

Comment: Ohh I just edited the code

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to add a value (fee $ 5) to the variable (var item = 10), and show the result. The tax value is in an external spreadsheet.

Comment: Your problem is due to the first line in the function, var tax = this.gsx$taxvalue.$t and the identifier "this" is different than the "this" in your getJson, so you need another way to get that value.

Comment: @DougF I tested it several times and didn't get a result that worked. How could I get this value differently?

Comment: One way you can go about it is moving the call to displayTax after your append in your getJson call.  This way you know that you have the value at the time you make the call.  Then in the displayTax function you can use something like var tax = $("#valueTax").text();  Keep in mind you need to convert that value as a number since you're doing math later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you are trying to access a variable when it does not exist, they are in different scopes.

I wrote an example of how you could solve this problem.

```js
function displayTax(tax) {
  const intTax = parseInt(tax, 10);
  $('.taxClass').html(tax);
  var item = 10;
  var total = item + intTax;
  $('.total-tax').html(total.toFixed(2));
}

function loadData() {
  var sheetURL =
"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1j3ri1WPLuw6IXXKYqrqNkSe_vU__YEXjyUSusR6G7ss/1/public/values?alt=json";
 $.getJSON(sheetURL, function(data) {
   var entryData = data.feed.entry;
   console.log(data);

   if(entryData) {
     // in case this array have more than one entry this will be overwritten 
      entryData.forEach(item => {
         displayTax(item['gsx$taxvalue']['$t']);  
      })
           
   }
   
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadData()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total-count"></div>
    
<div>Value Tax: $<span class="taxClass"></span> </div>
<div id="valueTax"></div>

<br>

<div>Total with tax: $<span class="total-tax"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `call` in your `displayTax()` function to set `this` inside the function to your desired object.

```
displayTax.call(yourTaxObject);
```

or in your case

```
displayTax.call(this);
```